# Google bots are indexing pages from the second domain on the server

Tags: apache, ssl, https

Could you help me? Recently my websites on the server were updated to HTTPS - vectorization-eu and pixsector-com. The problem is that google bots for some strange reason indexing pages from pixsector under vectorization-eu domain. Vectorization-eu doesn't have .htaccess file. Could be this an issue.
[PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjODp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Request removal of the URLs that do not exist on Google Search Console.

Upload a site maps to Google Search Console for each domain.